# How to get gnuplot to use a centered multi-line title, with left-aligned lines?

Tags: alignment, gnuplot, title, centering

I want my (gnu)plot to have a multi-line title. I would like the title to be *centered* (i.e. the distance from the center of the widest title line to the edges should be equal), but not to have each line centered *independently* of the others, which is the default behavior; I want to have the title lines left-aligned and *centered only as a block*.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

This is a bit tricky.  As said in the gnuplot documentation:

```
The `set title` command produces a plot title that is centered at the top of
the plot.  `set title` is a special case of `set label`.
```

Although the `label` command accepts a justification parameter, e.g.

```
set label "mylabel" right
```

`title` does not: it is hard-set to be centered.  The workaround I have is to use a `label` at the position where the title would be.  To make multiple lines use a newline (`\n`) within double quotes.

```
set title "\n"
set label 1 "first line\nsecond line" at graph 0.5,1.125 left
```

The dummy `set title` command is so that gnuplot adjusts the top margin for a two-line title.  I found that that position (0.5,1.125) reproduces the default title position well.  This won't center the label around the middle of the plot, though--it will be left- or right-justified to the center line.  The workaround would be to manually adjust the x-position of the label:

```
set title "\n"
shift = 0.05 # manually adjust
set label 1 "first line\nsecond line" at graph (0.5-shift),1.125 left
```

Comment: ... and can't I pre-calculate the width somehow?

Comment: Approximately, with the `strlen` command, which gives you the number of characters in a string.  I guess the method would be `strlen` the longest string for the label, convert between character width and screen coordinates, then shift by half the string length.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use a fixed width font and make all line the same length.

```
set term pngcairo size 800,600 font "Courier,10" enhanced crop

set title "\
Synchronic                        \n\
(. orange) signal columns         \n\
(+  green) planar signal          \n\
(.    red) paraboloid             \n\
(x  black) intersection           \n\
(|  black) detection              "
```

Comment: And will this work for just the title? ... Also, forcing a monospaced font is not that much better than having to live with non-left-aligned lines...